# $color from variables.scss in pug is unreadable with ngStyle

Tags: html, angular, pug, ng-style

Working with Angular2+, how can I get my $fam_1 value in the pug file with ngStyle?

In my variables.scss file :

```
$fam_1: #A474DB;
```

In my file.pug:

```
divName('[ngStyle]'="{'background-color' :'$fam_1'}")
```

Note : Putting directly '#f18973' instead of '$fam_1' works but i absolutly need a $color from variables.scss

Thanks for answer

Comment: SASS variables are only usable in SASS files, not in templates, afaik.

Comment: You can't do that.
But try to pass color variable into js property, then call it.